# FXSCopyButton Not working in IE, how to copy to clipboard in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, copy-paste

I have the following code on my page that displays a text box with a copy button after it(places the contents on your clipboard)...

```
    public showDialog(): DataLab.Util.Promise<IDialogResult> {
        var p = DialogViews.ShowApiCode.show(this);
        $("#short-code").fxsCopyButton({
            ariaLabelledBy: "short-code-label",
            labelElement: $("#short-code-input"),
            getClipboardText: function () { return $("#short-code-text").val(); }
        });
        $("#short-code-text").click(function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
        return p;
    }
```

This good works fine in Safari and in Chrome, but in IE the text box is empty. I know that if I remove the following the text books works fine...

```
         $("#short-code").fxsCopyButton({
```

Is my best option here to do a switch based on the browser and just not do clipboard in IE? Can I am I doing something wrong here, or is there a better way to do copy to clipboard for all browsers?

Comment: What version of IE? Remember that old IE implemented ES standard very left behind.

Comment: Currently Using IE11 probably the IE browser I want to focus on first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the clipboardData object instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx